# Action class keyDown and keyUp Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

Code trials:

```
searchbx.sendKeys("computer");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
searchbx.clear();
Thread.sleep(6000);
searchbx.click();
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("v").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

I am trying to run this but am getting the following error:

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keyDown argument must be an instanceof Keys: null
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.asKeys(Actions.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.keyDown(Actions.java:115)
    at protrainingtech.automationtrainingcourse.Key.main(Key.java:22)
```

I am trying to run the above code in selenium but getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to simulate `"CTRL + a"` and then `CTRL + "c"` you can use the below code: (using `searchbx` webelement as an example from your question)

**Code:**

```
searchbx.sendKeys("computer");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
//action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
searchbx.SendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + "a");
searchbx.SendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + "c"); 
Thread.sleep(6000);
searchbx.clear();
Thread.sleep(6000);
searchbx.click();
searchbx.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + "v");
```

You can interchangeably use `CONTROL` also in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
```

However, as per the [**Key down**](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/#key-down) documentation you can use the following code block:

```
Actions actionProvider = new Actions(driver);
Action keydown = actionProvider.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").build();
keydown.perform();
```

Comment: Thank you It is working just by adding import you suggested.

Comment: @Choudhry I suspected that right from the word go.